# For loop in Panda's Dataframe with if/else statement

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing three columns.

```
label2norm = label1norm.filter(['PRIMARYADDRESSEE','LAST_RENEWED_ON','AMOUNT'])
```

I want to build an if, else statement in a loop. It should read like this:

> If last renewed is NaN, add an "*" to 'PRIMARYADDRESSEE'
>
> if last renewed is NaN & the 'AMOUNT' is over 125, add "**" to 'PRIMARYADDRESSEE'
>
> Else skip it!

Everything I write is not working.

```
Names=[]
for x,y,z in label2norm.iterrows():
    if y.item == None:
        Names.append[x+'*']
        if z.item >= 125:
            Names.append[x+'*']
    else:
        Names.append[x]
```

Comment: You're not adding anything to 'primaryaddressee' you're writing to a list of 'Names'.

Answer (score 0):

For loops are very inefficient so I would use boolean indexing instead:

```
label1norm = pd.DataFrame([["A", None, 100], ["B", None, 200]], columns=['PRIMARYADDRESSEE','LAST_RENEWED_ON','AMOUNT'])
condition1 = label1norm["LAST_RENEWED_ON"].isna()
condition2 = (label1norm["LAST_RENEWED_ON"].isna() & (label1norm["AMOUNT"] >= 125))
label1norm.loc[condition1, "PRIMARYADDRESSEE"] = label1norm.loc[condition1, "PRIMARYADDRESSEE"] + "*"
label1norm.loc[condition2, "PRIMARYADDRESSEE"] = label1norm.loc[condition2, "PRIMARYADDRESSEE"] + "*"
print(label1norm)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is using the np.where function.

First deal with the above 125 and put ** in front of the Primary address.  Then the less than, and the other ones just fall through.

```
import numpy as np

label2norm = label1norm.filter(['PRIMARYADDRESSEE','LAST_RENEWED_ON','AMOUNT'])


label2norm['PRIMARYADDRESSEE'] =  np.where((label2norm['LAST_RENEWED_ON'].isnan() ) & 
                                           (label2norm['AMOUNT'] > 125) , 
                                           "**" + label2norm['PRIMARYADDRESSEE'],
                                           label2norm['PRIMARYADDRESSEE'])
label2norm['PRIMARYADDRESSEE'] = np.where((label2norm['LAST_RENEWED_ON'].isnan() ) & 
                                          (label2norm['AMOUNT'] <= 125) ,
                                          "*" + label2norm['PRIMARYADDRESSEE'],
                                          label2norm['PRIMARYADDRESSEE'])
```